# The media files are not being served in the dockerized django-react-postgresql portfolio from the database

Tags: django, docker, nginx, digital-ocean, django-media

I am building a dockerized personal portfolio using Django, React and PostgreSQL. The issue is, the images I am using are not found by the server in the deployed environment.

I am using **digitalocean** to deploy my portfolio by creating a droplet. I have already uploaded the images in django admin and I am fetching those via API in the react-frontend. This is working fine in the local environment, but the files are not found by the server in the deployed environment. I have tried using NginX for this as well but the issue persists. When I tried to locate that image via django admin panel again, status code 404 is there.

> Not Found
>
> The requested resource was not found on this server.

By this, at least I understood that the images I uploading to django admin are not being done successfully. However, when I check the media/images folder, inside the linux server, I can see all uploaded images.

[image: stored media files.]

I am using media_url in settings.py like this:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

I have tried to use NginX by installing it in the droplet and the updated the config file like this:

```
server {
    ...
    location /media/ {
        alias /home/kishan/my-portfolio/backend/media/images/;
        expires 30d;  # Adjust cache expiration as needed
    }
    ...
}
```

I added the media location so that nginx can serve the media files. I am not sure how to use nginx properly yet. But thought I should try and it did not work. The status 404 is there.

Comment: Thank you in advance to anyone who helps me out!!